# how to call a function in c# which return type is array

Tags: c#

```
public CD[] GetCDCatalog()
{
    XDocument docXML =
    XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("mydata.xml"));

    var CDs =
      from cd in docXML.Descendants("Table")
      select new CD
      {
          title = cd.Element("title").Value,
          star = cd.Element("star").Value,
          endTime = cd.Element("endTime").Value,

      };
    return CDs.ToArray<CD>();
}
```

I am calling this function on page load 
ie. string[] arr = GetCDCatalog();
but this is giving Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Calender.CD[]' to 'string[]' 
Please suggetst how can i call function on page load which return type is array.

Comment: I think your error is in the calling code. Are you doing something like `string[] cds = GetCDCatalog();`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your method is declared to return a `CD[]`, and as the compiler has told you, you can't convert from a `CD[]` to a `string[]`. Call it like this instead:

```
CD[] cds = GetCDCatalog();
```

If you need to convert to a string array then you could use something like this:

```
string[] cds = GetCDCatalog().Select(x => x.title).ToArray();
```

Or if you don't really need it in an array, you could just use:

```
IEnumerable<string> cds = GetCDCatalog().Select(x => x.title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the call in Page.Load to `Calender.CD[] arr = GetCDCatalog()`

Or use a List:

```
public List<CD> GetCDCatalog() { XDocument docXML = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("mydata.xml"));

    var CDs =
      from cd in docXML.Descendants("Table")
      select new CD
      {
          title = cd.Element("title").Value,
          star = cd.Element("star").Value,
          endTime = cd.Element("endTime").Value,

      };
    return CDs.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Better use an interface as returning type, like IList<CD> or ICollection<CD>.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling it as:

```
string[] arr = GetCDCatalog();
```

when GetCDCatalog is returning an array of CD (CD[]).

You need to do:

```
CD[] arr = GetCDCatalog();
```